# Kendo UI PHP - Filter on Template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI for PHP - Grid Control to display data.
Now my table structure is something like this: It has first_name and last_name but not name.
So I do this:

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));   

        echo json_encode($this->result->read('users', array('CONCAT(first_name, \' \', last_name) as name','first_name','last_name', 'country', 'status', 'city','role_id'), $request));
        exit;
```

However, now when I try to do the Filtering, it happens for country, city but not the "name" field. This is my code for creating the table on server side

```
$contactNameField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('name');
        $contactNameField->type('string');

        $firstNameField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('first_name');
        $firstNameField->type('string');

        $lastNameField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('last_name');
        $lastNameField->type('string');

        $contactCountryField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('country');
        $contactCountryField->type('string');

        $statusField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('status');
        $statusField->type('string');

        $cityField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('city');
        $cityField->type('string');
        $model->addField($contactNameField)
            ->addField($contactCountryField)
            ->addField($statusField)
            ->addField($firstNameField)
            ->addField($lastNameField)
            ->addField($cityField);

 $schema = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchema();
        $schema->data('data')
            ->errors('errors')
            ->groups('groups')
            ->model($model)
            ->total('total');
        $dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\DataSource();

        $dataSource->transport($transport)
            ->pageSize(10)
            ->serverPaging(true)
            ->serverSorting(true)
            ->serverGrouping(true)
            ->serverFiltering(true)
            ->schema($schema);

        $gridFilterable = new \Kendo\UI\GridFilterable();
        $gridFilterable->mode("row");
 $contactName = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
        $contactName->field('name')

            ->title('Name')
            ->filterable(true)
            ->sortable(true)
            ->width(240);

 $status = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
        $status->field('status')
            ->title('status');

        $city = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
        $city->field('city')
            ->width(150);

$grid->addColumn($contactName, $country , $status, $city)          
            ->dataSource($dataSource)
            ->toolbarTemplateId('toolbar')
            ->sortable(true)
            ->filterable($gridFilterable)
            ->groupable(true)
            ->pageable($pageable)
            ->attr('style', 'height:550px');
```

This is the error from logs
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in DataSourceResult.php:540

Comment: Can somebody help?